# How to show $T$ is bounded, not compact and doesn't have eigen values

Tags: functional-analysis

If $T:L^2(0, 1)\rightarrow L^2(0, 1)$ defined by $(Tf)(x)=xf(x), f\in L^2(0, 1)$ then how to show that

1. $T$ is a bounded linear operator with $T=T^*,$
2. $T$ is not a
       compact operator and $T$ doesn't have eigen values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$T$ is bounded because
$||Tf||^2=\int_0^1|xf(x)|^2dx\leq\int_0^1|f(x)|^2=||f||^2$ implies $||T||\leq 1$.
Furthermore
$(Tf,g)=\int_0^1xf(x)g(x)dx=\int_0^1f(x)xg(x)dx=(f,Tg)$ for all $f,g\in L^2([0,1])$
implies $T=T^*$. The sequence $\{f_j\}$ where $f_j(x)=x^j$ is bounded with $||f_j||=1$ but its image under $T$ is $\{f_{j+1}\}$ is not precompact, has no convergent subsequence. Finally the equation $Tf=\lambda f$ leads to $xf(x)=\lambda f(x)$ and this to $f\equiv 0$. Thus $T$ has no eigenvalues despite the fact it is selfadjoint.